# Finding Calculus or Probability error in basic continuous probability problem

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-theory

I am having a lot of difficulty spotting my error in the following probability problem.

> > The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $f(x,y) =  c\left (y^2-x^2\right)e^{-y}, \ \ \ \ -y \le x \le y,\ \ \  0 \lt y \lt \infty
> > $
>
> Find $E[X]$

I do not know if I have made a probability or calculus mistake somewhere in my work. First finding $c$, I have $c= \Large\frac{1}{8}$. Next, finding $f_{X}(x)$ I have 
$$f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{8}\int_{-y}^{y}(y^2-x^2)e^{-y} \mathrm{dy} = \frac{1}{8}(2-x^2) $$

Finally, to find $E[X]$ I have

$$E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X}(x) \mathrm{dx}  = \frac{1}{8}\int_{-y}^{y} x(y^2-x^2)e^{-y} \mathrm{dy} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{4} - \frac{x^3}{8} \mathrm{dx}  $$

which does not converge. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems to me that $E[X]$ must exist here, and so this integral (or some other integral) must converge.

Have I missed something fundamental to probability, or have I possibly made a calculus mistake somewhere here?

Comment: It looks like posting more of my work would help. Working on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ f_X(x) = c \int_{|x|}^\infty (y^2-x^2) e^{-y} \, dy $$